# Rated load of a transformer

Tags: transformer

When the transformer is operating in rated apparent power, the voltage and current at the secondary side(is it the secondary side, please verify) is the rated voltage and current. My question is what is the rated load?

Comment: should be ohmic load

Answer (score 1):

The rated load is the value of load resistance that will draw the rated transformer current at the rated transformer voltage.  For example, a line transformer that has a primary voltage of 120 VAC and a secondary voltage of 24 VAC that is rated for 2 amperes of current has a rated load of 24/2 ohms which is 12 ohms.  Thus if a 12 ohm resistor is placed across the secondary of this transformer, it will draw 2 amperes, the rated current of the transformer.